# BibDesk: Preview with your favourite biblatex-style

Tags: biblatex, bibdesk

I use BibDesk to organise my library and implement quotations through `biblatex` in my  documents.

BibDesk has this feature of allowing the user to see a BiBTeX-preview (not `biblatex`!) of the currently selected publication at the bottom or the sidebar. You can choose between different styles (like `ieeetr`, `alpha`, `abrvnat` etc.).

Until now I never thought about using this preview, because (1) I did not find a style I like and (2) it does not render my `biblatex` commands and types properly.

So, instead I used the following .`tex` file (which I found somewhere on the net and modified):

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, DIV=13]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[   Numbers=OldStyle,
            Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[    style=reading,
            abstract=false,
            abbreviate=false,
            backend=biber
                ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{BibLaTeX.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This `.tex` file creates a PDF listing all the publications I have in my `.bib` file. With this PDF I could easily check and see whether references are properly set. However, creating this PDF file takes rather long, as my library is growing... And anyway it is rather a detour, to be honest, given that there actually **is** a preview feature implemented into BibDesk.

My question now is: Is it possible to preview my `biblatex` references with BibDesk's preview-feature using the style I used in the `.tex` file shown above? What do I have to change in the settings of BibDesk in order to generate a `biblatex` output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to use biblatex with Bibdesk to generate the TeX preview.

Go to `Preferences` --> `TeX preview`

Then if you want to use XeLaTeX change the executable for `pdflatex` to `xelatex`

[image]

Then you have to change the TeX template. Based on what you have provided a suitable template is.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, DIV=13]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[   Numbers=OldStyle,
            Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[    style=reading,
            abstract=false,
            abbreviate=false,
            backend=bibtex
                ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{<<File>>}
\pagestyle{empty}
\textwidth = 6.5in
\renewcommand{\refname}{}

% The following command is provided for LaTeX2RTF compatibility with amslatex.
\newif\iflatextortf
\iflatextortf
\providecommand{\bysame}{\_\_\_\_\_}
\fi

\begin{document}
\nocite{<<CiteKeys>>}   
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

After that you are ready to generate the preview (I am not been able to use `biber` as backend). Also I would suggest to use `pdflatex`  instead of `xelatex` given that the generation with `xelatex` is slower.

Comment: While basic preview can easily be achieved with `BibDesk` and `biblatex/biber` there are limits to this combo. Basically, `BibDesk` doesn't know how to handle any of `biblatex`'s linked entries by the `xref` or related entries entries. For `bibtex` traditional crossref fields `BibDesk` will search for the linked entry and display everything correctly. But if you want to display an entry making use of `biblatex`'s related feature you have to select both entries by hand. Unfortunately, `BibDesk`'s developers are not interested in improving this.

Comment: @Simifilm I also saw your other post on the BibDesk mailing list, and was wondering, in recent years have you come up with any solution/workaround for BibDesk's poor handling of `related` and `xref` entries? (I'm having the same issue as you have it seems, using `biblatex-chicago`)

Comment: @jan Nothing has really happened here. Unfortunately, the `BibDesk` developers are really not into `biblatex`. I would love if someone created a `biberDesk` fork, but this does not seem very likely ATM.

Comment: @Simifilm A `biberDesk` would indeed be awesome!  I use `biblatex-chicago` and for the accurate rendering of reviews or translated works it's really impossible without using the biblatex `related` fields. The problem is also that BibDesk doesn't update citekeys in these fields as it does for traditional crossrefs. I wish they would consider adding that as an option but I also have little hope. I might try to politely ask about these features via the list as maybe there are others who would support our case ... and maybe if there is enough interest they'll reconsider.