# Is it possible to use CSL (citation style language) files in Latex

Tags: bibliographies, citing, bibliographystyle, csl

CSL files are a popular way to share citation styles.
See for example https://www.zotero.org/styles.
Is there a way to use these files in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  In your text, I think you want to change "CLS" to "CSL" to match the title.

Comment: @Marijn Are you sure that this old thread (2012, with a newer answer from 2016) reflects the current state of affairs? Don't you think it might be worth to wait a bit with closing the question in order to see whether someone has newer information?

Comment: @gernot no, I am not sure that the old question and answers are still valid. However, if there is a newer answer possible, then it should be posted on the other question, not here. Duplicates are intended to prevent fragmentation of information about the same question, which is why I voted to close. It could be that closing this question now will cause it to get less attention, but I hope that people with the relevant expertise will still choose to look at the question even if it is closed, then go to the other question, and then post a new answer there.

Comment: @Marijn Closed questions are only visible to the OP and to users with the open/close privilege. By closing a question prematurely, you reduce the chance that the question receives sufficient attention for attracting new answers. Moreover, will SX notify the OP if a new answer is posted in the alleged duplicate? I don't think so. As it stands, the premature closing will just appear as an unfriendly act to the new user, without delivering much added value to this site.

Comment: @gernot you first statement is not true, everybody can see closed questions (for example I don't have the open/close privilege on Stack Overflow but I can see closed questions there). The the OP will not be notified of a new answer to the duplicate but he can click 'follow' on that question if he wants to get automatic notifications of activity on that question. The added value of closing is that information is not duplicated and people are redirected to the linked question if they happen to find this one, instead of people finding the questions separately and getting incomplete information.

Comment: @Marijn You are right, I misinterpreted the line `Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege` under an add-on in the closing message as pertaining to the whole message, not just to the add-on (that you probably don't see). Still, you expect a lot from a new user: understanding the mechanics of the site (by following the old thread) and not to take it personal. And from potential contributors: not to skip over a duplicate but to find out that the old answers are obsolete. Closing  a non-offensive question quickly remains an unfriendly act, and unproductive.

Comment: @gernot I started a bounty on the other question to try to attract new answers. If they appear we can notify the OP here.

Comment: @Marijn See for some newer comments https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435004/2388

Comment: @Marijn Nice move!

Comment: @ user3204114 there was indeed a new answer posted to the other question (direct link to answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618815/89417) that may be able to help you.