# How to use the ``citekey'' as the info in brackets for richtext?

Tags: citing, bibdesk

When I ask for ``Copy Rich Text'' for a citation, I get something like this:

[Pelz and Canosa, 2001] Pelz, J. B. and Canosa, R. (2001). Oculomotor behavior and perceptual strategies in complex tasks. Vision Research, 41(25-26):3587–3596.

or this

[Stevenson et al., 2019] Stevenson, M. P., Dewhurst, R., Schilhab, T., and Bentsen, P. (2019). Cognitive restoration in children following exposure to nature: Evidence from the attention network task and mobile eye tracking. Frontiers in Psychology, 10(FEB).

However, the info in the brackets is worthless to me and I would like to replace it with my Cite Key info. For example,

[pelz01visRsch] Pelz, J. B. and Canosa, R. (2001). Oculomotor behavior and perceptual strategies in complex tasks. Vision Research, 41(25-26):3587–3596.

or

[stevenson19fip] Stevenson, M. P., Dewhurst, R., Schilhab, T., and Bentsen, P. (2019). Cognitive restoration in children following exposure to nature: Evidence from the attention network task and mobile eye tracking. Frontiers in Psychology, 10(FEB).

Seems like there should be a simple fix but I have been using BibDesk for several decades and have not yet stumbled on the solution!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "Copy Rich Text" command copies a rich text version of BibDesk's TeX Preview (via LaTeX2RTF). The copied citation style is the BibTeX style that is selected in the [TeX Preview pane of BibDesk's preferences](https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/manual/BibDeskHelp_66.html).

If you have a BibTeX style file in your TeX installation that corresponds to the citation style that you want to copy, you should select that BibTeX style file in the TeX Preview pane of BibDesk's preferences.

If you don't have such a BibTeX style file, then there are several options:

1. [Make a custom .bst file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85432/where-the-bst-file-comes-in) and select it in BibDesk's preferences.
2. [Edit BibDesk's TeX preview template to use BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91584/bibdesk-preview-with-your-favourite-biblatex-style) instead of BibTeX, and make a custom citation style for BibLaTeX.
3. [Choose another way of formatting citations](https://sourceforge.net/p/bibdesk/wiki/Format_Citations_for_Editors/). A common alternative way to format citations in BibDesk is to use [BibDesk's export templates](https://sourceforge.net/p/bibdesk/wiki/Templates/).

Pursuing option three, [BibDesk's graphical template editor](https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/manual/BibDeskHelp_61.html) allows creating some basic templates without the need to know [BibDesk's template syntax](https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/manual/BibDeskHelp_94.html), but if you wish to learn the syntax there is a [list of template keys in the BibDesk manual](https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/manual/BibDeskHelp_95.html). The template key for a citekey is `<$citeKey/>`. For example, here is a template that would give the citekey in square brackets and a citation style like the one above for an article (and DOI field at the end):

```
<$publications>
<?$pubType=article?>
[<$citeKey/>] <$authors.normalizedAbbreviatedName.@componentsJoinedByCommaAndAnd/><$authors.@count=0?><$editors.normalizedAbbreviatedName.@componentsJoinedByCommaAndAnd/><$editors.@count=0?><?$editors.@count=1?> (ed.)<?$editors.@count?> (eds.)</$editors.@count?></$authors.@count?> (<$fields.Year/>). <$fields.Title/>. <$fields.Journal/><$fields.Volume?>, <$fields.Volume/></$fields.Volume?><$fields.Number?>(<$fields.Number/>)</$fields.Number?>:<$fields.Pages?>, <$fields.Pages/></$fields.Pages?>.<$fields.Doi?> http://dx.doi.org/<$fields.Doi/></$fields.Doi?>
</$pubType?>
</$publications>
```

To use this template you would save it in your desired format (such as plain text or rich text), and then [add it to BibDesk's Templates preference pane](https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/manual/BibDeskHelp_70.html), and then select "Copy Using Template > (Your Template Name)" instead of "Copy Rich Text". You could even make your custom template the default in [BibDesk's Citation preference pane](https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/manual/BibDeskHelp_65.html). But a complete template would also have template keys for other item types (book, incollection, etc.) if you have other item types in your BibDesk database.